# wget|sudo fails in Ansible command

Tags: clang, wget, ansible

I am trying to write a simple ansible script to install the latest clang / llvm toolchain, but I can't get the second statement to run.

It is based on: http://llvm.org/apt/ for ubuntu

```
---
- name: add llvm toolchain repo for {{ ubuntu_version }}
   apt_repository: repo='deb http://llvm.org/apt/{{ubuntu_version }}/ llvm-toolchain-{{ ubuntu_version }} main'
   sudo: yes

- name: add key toolchain (does not work)
  command: wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
  sudo: yes

- name: install llvm and clang
  apt: pkg={{item}} state=latest update_cache=yes
  with_items: clang_packages
  sudo: yes
```

Anybody any idea what might be the problem. It works if I run "wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key #add -" manually at the command-line

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: # is comment in YAML syntax. Maybe that's it?

Comment: You would be better off replacing this whole wget line with apt_key module instead: http://docs.ansible.com/apt_key_module.html

Comment: @Mikko this was a typo. corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html):

> It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work (use the shell module if you need these features)

Answer (score 3):

Based on mgsk and Slava's response I have rewritten my script to use

```
- name: add key toolchain
  apt_key: url=http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key state=present
  sudo: yes
```